# Is it possible to have a same-day walk-in appointment at the Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei (Taipei City, Da'an District)?

Tags: taiwan, global-entry, taipei

Is it possible to have a same-day walk-in appointment at the [Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei (Taipei City, Da'an District)](https://goo.gl/maps/q3LcyLSKpFY8QPkA8)?

I couldn't find the information on the Global Entry's official website (https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/schedulerui/):

[image: e]

---

I tried to call the Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei (‪‪+886 2 2162 2000‬, phone number found on Google Maps‬): ‪no human answer this line, I tried all the options in the menu and the best I could obtain was another phone number for visa applications (+886 2 7741 7989, and I know that Global Entry has nothing to do with visas). Calling +886 2 7741 7989, then using options `5, 1, 2`, I finally got a human on the line, who had no clue regarding appointments for the Global Entry program, but gave me an email address (visaiv-ait@state.gov). I emailed them and I am currently waiting to hear back from them.  I also asked the question on the Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei's Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/AIT.Social.Media/posts/10157425636918490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, walk-ins are not accepted as the Center is not mentioned on this [website](https://millionmilesecrets.com/guides/get-a-same-day-walk-in-appointment-at-these-global-entry-enrollment-centers/) under *Global Entry Enrollment Centers That Accept Walk-Ins*.

Answer (score 0):

The American Institute in Taiwan confirmed by email that there is no Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei currently.

> ---------- Forwarded message ---------
>    From: AIT Non-Immigrant Visa Unit `<VISANIV-AIT@state.gov>`
>  Date: Mon, 9 Sep 2019 at 01:30 
> Subject:
>   FW: Is it possible to have a same-day walk-in appointment at the
>   Global Entry Enrollment Center in Taipei (Taipei City, Da'an
>   District)?
>
> Thank you for your email. We are sorry that there is no Global Entry
>   Enrollment Center in Taipei currently. Please visit the link to find
>   your nearest enrollment
>   Center.https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-centers
>
> Sincerely,
>    Non-Immigrant Visa Unit Consular Section American
>   Institute in Taiwan 
> www.ait.org.tw
>   
> No. 100, Jinhu Road, Neihu District
>   11461, Taipei City, Taiwan  美國在台協會領事組非移民簽證科nl

Interestingly, the list of https://www.cbp.gov/travel/trusted-traveler-programs/global-entry/enrollment-centers  doesn't match the list on https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/schedulerui/.